# Scrapy issue with pagination using ScrapyCrawl

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Hi everyone,
Hope you are well,
I am building a basic spider using CrawlSpider to crawl through Indeed website, I picked a random company reviews (just for training purpose).
Please see my code below.
There are 84 reviews but only 64 are being scraped, it goes through all pages and scrape all information required but all reviews from the page 1 are not being scraped.

When I run the spider here is the result a get:

2020-06-17 19:54:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://www.indeed.co.uk/robots.txt> (referer: None)

**2020-06-17 19:54:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://www.indeed.co.uk/cmp/Benugo/reviews> (referer: None)**

2020-06-17 19:54:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://www.indeed.co.uk/cmp/Benugo/reviews?start=20> (referer: https://www.indeed.co.uk/cmp/Benugo/reviews)

The second page with job titles printing starts here.

I noticed that the first page line return (in bold) has referer set to None, would this be the reason?

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor




class RevSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'review'
allowed_domains = ["indeed.co.uk"]
start_urls = ['https://www.indeed.co.uk/cmp/Benugo/reviews']

rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@data-tn-element="next-page"]',)), callback="parse_page", follow=True),)


def parse_page(self, response):
    all_reviews = response.xpath('//div[@class="cmp-Review"]')
    for review in all_reviews:
        job_title = review.xpath('.//a[@class="cmp-ReviewAuthor-link"][1]/text()').extract()
        print(job_title)
```

Thank you, 
Arnaud.

Comment: Why don't you try without the Rule?

Comment: @Juanje thank you, I know it is feasible using other ways like the absolute URL and Request object, but as there is a way with using the rule I would like to understand the process fully and why it is not working, if that make sense.

Comment: Please, try to be concise in your questions and [minimize code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as much as possible.

Comment: @Gallaecio, Hi Gallaecio, thank you for taking time, I will revise right now

Comment: I suggest you inspect the response that you get for that URL using `scrapy shell`.

Comment: @Gallaecio, Hi Gallaecio, I figured the issue out. With the code above, all scraped results started from page 2 without going through page 1, it was due to the rule I put in place which extracted the link to jump on the next page then went on proceeding with the parse_page function To solve it I added another rule which extracts the link that lead to  page 1 from the main page and call back the parse_page function. Hope it makes sense. Thank you for support